# Is it possible to not receive a completion for a WSASend call?

Tags: c, winapi, tcp, winsock2, iocp

Like the title says, is it possible for a **successful** `WSASend` call on a socket associated with an I/O completion port to not post a completion for any reason other than the thread ending?

I have a strange situation where it looks like a completion isn't being posted for a `WSASend`, which results in a socket leak; the application thinks a send is still pending for the socket and refuses to release it.

The send code is as follows:

```
void CSocketServer::Write(
    Socket *pSocket,
    CIOBuffer *pBuffer) const
{
    pSocket->AddRef();

    pBuffer->SetOperation(IO_Write_Completed);
    pBuffer->SetupWrite();
    pBuffer->AddRef();

    DWORD dwFlags = 0;
    DWORD dwSendNumBytes = 0;

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == ::WSASend(
        pSocket->m_socket,
        pBuffer->GetWSABUF(), 
        1, 
        &dwSendNumBytes,
        dwFlags,
        pBuffer, 
        NULL))
    {
        DWORD lastError = ::WSAGetLastError();

        if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != lastError)
        {
            pSocket->OnConnectionError(WriteError, pBuffer, lastError);

            pSocket->WriteCompleted();  // this pending write will never complete...

            pSocket->Release();
            pBuffer->Release();
        }
    }
    // Note: even if WSASend returns SUCCESS an IO Completion Packet is 
    // queued to the IOCP the same as if ERROR_IO_PENDING was returned.
    // Thus we need no special handling for the non error return case.
    // See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q192800
    // for details.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any of the funky new features, like turning off completions for successful calls using `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS`?

Are you doing any form of flow control on your sends or are you just sending whenever you feel like it and as often as you want? What you MIGHT be seeing is simply a SLOW completion due to the fact that the TCP stack is doing congestion control and cant send your data yet. If you keep sending data in an uncontrolled manner you can often get into a situation where completions start taking longer and longer to occur. Especially if you are sending data at a faster rate than the TCP connection is successfully getting it to the other side and especially if the TCP window isn't that big. See here: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2008/07/write-completion-flow-control.html for some more information.

Of course it could simply be a bug in your send logic, could you post some code?

Note that there's a known bug with WSARecv() and UDP (so nothing to do with your question at all) when using `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` which gives the situation that you describe if the datagram is bigger than the buffer that you supply and the `WSARecv()` call would have generated an `WSAEMOREDATA`; see here: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2010/01/file-skip-completion-port-on-success-and-datagram-socket-read-errors.html

Comment: I think I might be using a 5-7 year old, heavily modified version of your server framework. It's not a slow completion, as there's no congestion, but I'm seeing some sockets that are never deallocated. Dumping them shows that they have one reference and one outstanding write. If I wait 24 hours and dump them again, these sockets are still there. It's probably a bug in the logic somewhere, I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: I don't provide support for the free code, and even less ;) for heavily modified versions of it, but, it does sound like a logic bug. Post the code that issues the send?

Comment: I've pasted the `Write` function, I'm not sure how much of it is yours, though. Another thread posts an `IO_Write_Request` operation to the I/O thread, and that handles it and enters this function.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much all mine, unlikely to be a bug in there as there are a LOT of people using The Free Framework without problems for several years. I assume that the write isn't actually getting through to the peer? Or is it getting through and still not 'completing' in the server? Could you simply have a deadlock in your I/O pool, or have lost I/O threads?

Comment: There's only one I/O thread in the pool, so that shouldn't be an issue. I'm not sure if the peer is getting the write, unfortunately, I can't reproduce this in a test environment. I would hazard a guess that it's not, though, because this always occurs with a fairly new socket. There are never more than 2 or 3 completed reads.

Comment: All I can suggest is to a) switch to the latest version of the free code (http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html) as it may contain some bug fixes that you don't have if you're using the original CodeProject version and b) check that some error case completions aren't failing to decrement both the pending write counter and the socket's ref count...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to prevent a completion port from posting by setting the low bit of an `OVERLAPPED` structure's valid `hEvent`:

From documentation for [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364986%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Even if you have passed the function a
>   file handle associated with a
>   completion port and a valid OVERLAPPED
>   structure, an application can prevent
>   completion port notification. This is
>   done by specifying a valid event
>   handle for the hEvent member of the
>   OVERLAPPED structure, and setting its
>   low-order bit. A valid event handle
>   whose low-order bit is set keeps I/O
>   completion from being queued to the
>   completion port.

Comment: Interesting. Given the code he's using it's unlikely that this is the cause of his problem unless he has 'heavily modified' that area a lot... The base code that he's working from doesn't use events in the overlapped structures at all.